# Search for value in column and overwrite the row, otherwise add new row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script that allows users to enter data into a spreadsheet using an HTML form. I'm trying to implement a feature where the script searches through a column for a string from the form: if found, the old data in the row should be overwritten with data from the form; if not, the data should be appended as a new row.

This the snippet I have right now:

```
    var col4 = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
    var searchCol4 = SSNs.createTextFinder(e.parameter.Col4);
    searchCol4.matchEntireCell(true);
    var existingCol4Row = searchCol4.findNext().getRow();

    if (existingCol4Row !== null) {
      var nextRow = existingCol4Row
    } else {
      var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    }

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
```

The problem I have is that the script only works if it finds a match in the column; if it doesn't, it doesn't add a new row as it should.
If I replace the whole `if ...` statement with `var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1` then the script appends new rows, but obviously it doesn't replace old data anymore. I've also tried changing the condition to just `existingCol4Row`, with the same result.

Any tips?

---

EDIT: I got the code working, thanks to ziganotschka. I changed the conditional statement to check if `searchCol4.findNext()` was `null` rather than `searchCol4.findNext().getRow()`. I also made sure the code would only call `.getRow()` if `searchCol4.findNext()` wasn't `null`, as calling the method on a null range seems to make the code fail (anything past that line wouldn't run, including logging). Here's the working snippet:

```
var Col4 = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
    var searchCol4 = Col4.createTextFinder(e.parameter.Col4);
    searchCol4.matchEntireCell(true);
    var existingCol4 = searchCol4.findNext();

    if (existingCol4 !== null) {
      var nextRow = existingCol4.getRow();
    } else {
      var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log `searchSSNs.findNext()` and `searchSSNs.findNext().getRow()`.

### Result

If `searchSSNs.findNext()` is `NULL`, `getRow()` will return you the first row of the search range, so in your case row 2.

Thus,

**`searchSSNs.findNext().getRow()` will never be `NULL`**

### Solution

Change your conditional statement to

`if (searchSSNs.findNext() !== null) {`

> Sidenote: There is a confusion with the name of your textfinder range
>   (`searchSSNs` or `searchCol4`?), I assume this is jsut a typing
>   mistake.

Comment: Thank you, I got the code to work. I changed the conditional statement to `if (searchCol4.findNext() !== null)` and made the code only call `getRow()` if the condition was true, as calling the method on a null range seems to make the code crash. I'll add an edit to the OP.